# What is this special, general type of atomic sentence?

Tags: logic, modal-logic

There is exactly one atomic sentence form of L (call it 'A'), which is always a tautology, and whose negation 'negate A', is always a formal contradiction. What is this special, general type of atomic sentence?

I know that it must be a two-place relation but beyond that I don't know what it
could possibly be.

Comment: Can you specify a little further what exactly you'd like someone here to explain to you? What hypotheses have you formed, what has your research uncovered so far, etc.?

Comment: Well I would like to know what atomic sentence the question is asking me to find. As far as research I have none, we have no book for the class , notes are very cryptic and taken from in class.

Answer (score 3):

Some logics have a nullary truth-functional connective (⊤) that evaluates to true under all valuations. You can call it 'A', you can call it 'atomic', if you so desire. Here are some facts about ⊤:

- It's special in that its interpretation is fixed, i.e., ⊤ is a [logical constant](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logical-constants/). That means that truth-assignments (like the rows of truth-tables) cannot alter its truth value.
- It's general in that it can be used to represent the *equivalence class* of all tautologies in a given logic (the set of all φ, ψ s.t. φ ⇆ ψ). Because if φ and ψ are tautologies, then φ ≡ ψ ≡ ⊤.

I'm not sure if that's what you're looking for. I have to admit that the question wasn't very clear.